# How to get the Facebook "HashTag" feeds/Posts etc using the Facebook Graph API ? I want to get all the posts of a particular #HashTag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

I have suitation, where i have to get all the posts of Particular HashTag  of Facebook. eg  #ILovePhp . I have done some R&D and got my own profile hashtag posts/comments in format of  JSON. But i want all the Posts of the particular HashTag(i.e a user who is not friend at all to me in facebook still he posted some message using the hash tag #ILovePhp) . I want to get all the posts in Facebook related to a particulat HashTag. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public Post Search has been removed, there is no way to get all posts of a particular hashtag anymore. You can read more about that in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).